# Laravel 5.4 + vue2 click Event Handling not working

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I have problem with Event Handling in vue2 with Laravel 5.4 - nothing happen when i use click event on the button. No error or anything else.

My html (in fact its **header.blade.php**):

```
<div id="example">
  <button v-on:click="exclick">Super btn</button>
</div>
```

My js (**app.js in resources/assets folder**)

```
require('./bootstrap');

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  methods: {
    exclick: function (event) {
      alert("Log 1");
      if (event) {
        alert("Log 2");
      }
    }
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**JS compiled by gulp**

Please help!

Comment: Is `app.js` in the header, or at the bottom of the blade? Also, you're creating two Vues. If one is inside the other, that is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: app.js is in the bottom, after #app is closed. If seen the examples, we can create many of Vues elements inside the main #app element

Comment: Is `#example` *inside* `#app`?

Comment: Yes,#example  is inside #app

Comment: That's your problem. You cannot nest the templates.

Comment: I must create all events handler in one methods in const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  methods: {
    // --------
  }
}); ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150352/discussion-between-kogoro-and-bert-evans).

Comment: Yes, that, or move `#example` *outside* of `#app`.